# How to print rows and columns of missing values using NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan, locate

```
for i in range(19):
    for j in range(5):
        if df.iloc[i,j] == 'NaN':
            print('Missing Value at (row,col): ({}, {}) '.format(i,j))
```

Comment: use `pd.isnull`. `pd.isnull(df.iloc[i, j])`

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this, hope it helps:)
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# importing numpy
import numpy as np

# dictionary of lists
dict = {'First Score':[100, 90, np.nan, 95],
        'Second Score': [30, 45, 56, np.nan],
        'Third Score':[np.nan, 40, 80, 98]}

# creating a dataframe using dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# using notnull() function
df.notnull()
```